# Wowonder 4.0.1 Login Loop

Tags: php

I woke up one morning and found my Wowonder website had stopped letting people login. When you try it goes into a login loop taking you right back to the login again.

I installed a second copy in a new location and works fine. I even tried changing my current one to a new DB and it worked fine.

I was told to go to Varibles under phpmyadmin by a guy who runs Wowonder himself and search for mode. That brought up sql_mode and he told me to remove everything on that line except for: NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION so I did and still loops (attaching screenshot of it).

If anyone has any suggestions let me know. I have 400+ members and don't want to start over.

[MySQL Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEEi6.png)

Comment: This is going to need a bit of actual debugging, we can't tell you what might be wrong based on nothing but a screenshot of a bit of MySQL configuration settings.

Comment: You forgot to share the code involved, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I did not receive email notifications so I figured no one had answered. Any way it was solved, thank for replying at least.

Answer (score -1):

I guess since no one answered, I'll give the way I fixed it:

SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'

Run that command under the varibles tab in phpmyadmin to fix thwe issue.

Hope this helps you!!!

Comment: So... you basically done what that guy has told you to do? Why even post question then?

Comment: I did not know how to do this until I got someone on fiverr who told me how to fix it after I had posted this question.